# Link to search by attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, search

I have a traditional slider on the homepage and I need one of the slides to link to a list of products that contain the same attribute. In this case I have a manufacturer called Zodiac that goes by the ID 17 and I need the link to go to the products made by such brand. I need to add the link in the backend so I cannot use php, I just have a text input to fill it in. How is the best way to do this?

I tried this:

```
{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}catalogsearch/result/index?manufacturer=17
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
{{store url="catalogsearch/advanced/result" _query="manufacturer=17"}}
```

And make sure the attribute `manufacturer` is marked as 'Use in advanced search'.

Comment: Mmmh, apparently the extension I am using for the slideshow is giving me trouble adding even that to the input text where the link goes :S (it's banner slider)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the extension. This is the code that works in a cms page or cms block. You can modify the extension to support these types of links. Let's say the value you enter for the link is in the variable `$_link`. Then you need the following processing `$_link = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($_link)`. This should work.

Comment: In the end adding just "catalogsearch/advanced/result?manufacturer=17" to the input would do the trick because I was already on the homepage but this is a perfectly acceptable answer for the question, thanks!